# How to exclude fields from RequestBody - Swagger

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

I have this DTO:

```
public class UserTo extends AbstractBaseTo {

@NotBlank(message = "Name must not be blank")
@Size(min = 2, max = 100, message = "Name length must be between 2 and 100 characters")
private String name;

@Email(message = "Email must accord email pattern")
@NotBlank(message = "Email must not be blank")
@Size(max = 100, message = "Email length must be 100 characters max")
private String email;

@NotBlank(message = "Password must not be blank")
@Size(min = 5, max = 32, message = "Password length must be between 5 and 32 characters")
private String password;
.......
```

I use this DTO in many methods of my UserController, but, for example, in Login method i use only two fields of that: email and password.

When i use Swagger to create documentation to my API, it shows all fields of UserTo in documentation for Login method. I want that it shows only two fields. How can i do this? I do not want to create additional DTOs (with 2 or 3 fields, you know). I tried to use @RequestBody annotation from Swagger for create some example of needed RequestBody, but it doesn't work.

I use Spring Boot and springfox 3.0.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can hide parameters from swagger ui, by using

```
@ApiModelProperty(hidden = true)
```

with the fields you do not want to show. But the hidden fields will be hidden for every api in your swagger ui.

There is another way which requires you to create another dto. You can create another Dto and ask springfox show the new alternate dto instead of the original one.

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/someapi")
    @ApiImplicitParams({
            @ApiImplicitParam(
                    name = "request",
                    dataTypeClass = AdditionalModel.class
            )
    })
    public Response hello(@RequestBody Request request){
        return new Response();
    }
```

This approach will not make you change your code, but you will be required to create another dto.
Also you also need to register the AdditionalModel in your Docket Bean.

```
    @Bean
    public Docket petApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build()
                .pathMapping("/")
           .additionalModels(typeResolver.resolve(AdditionalModel.class));
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! But i need that in one endpoint they will be hidden and on another they were not. I think there is some Swagger annotation or config for customize RequestBody for each endpoint, but i do not know how to do this.

Comment: I tried this with AdditionalModel DTO, but in this case in Swagger UI i have an empty Example value. How to fix this?

Comment: Sorry, if you did not use the Additional Model anywhere else, then you need to register the model manually, I have updated my answer.

Comment: Man, it works! You got my day! Thank you very much, man!

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit outdated answer, but i hit similar problem when was designing my Api: when you have single DTO for request and response schema.

My work around was using @Schema with accessMode = Schema.AccessMode.READ_ONLY on fields that required hiding in POST PUT operations

```
@Schema(description = "Category of ingredients")
public record CategoryDTO (
        @Digits(integer = 20, fraction = 0)
        @Min(0)
        @Max(Long.MAX_VALUE)
        @Schema(description = "Id of category, autogenerated value, please ignore for POST operations")
        Long categoryId,

        @NotNull(message = "{validation.companyId}")
        @Digits(integer = 20, fraction = 0)
        @Min(0)
        @Max(Long.MAX_VALUE)
        @Schema(description = "Id of company category belongs to.")
        Long categoryCompanyId,
        @NotBlank
        @Length(max = 45, message = "{validation.size.45}")
        String categoryName,
        @Digits(integer = 20, fraction = 0)
        @Min(0)
        @Max(Long.MAX_VALUE)
        @Schema(description = "Id of parent category, if is null then it is root category, " +
                "please assign the value to place in specific branch")
        Long parentCategoryId,

        @Schema(accessMode = Schema.AccessMode.READ_ONLY)
        String parentCategoryName,
        String categoryImage,
        @Schema(accessMode = Schema.AccessMode.READ_ONLY)
        LocalDateTime dateCreated,
        @Schema(accessMode = Schema.AccessMode.READ_ONLY)
        LocalDateTime dateUpdated,
        @Schema(accessMode = Schema.AccessMode.READ_ONLY)
        Set<CategoryDTO> categoryCategories

) implements Serializable {
        @Serial
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; }
```

Might be usefull for some1 looking for same solution

Comment: hi there, did you ever encounter this case, where 1 DTO is used for different end points. But you hid some fields for 1 endPoint but other endPoints saw all the fields in Swagger UI?

Comment: @mfaisalhyder as far as i am aware you can not do it at this point of time, swagger model (Schema / DTO) customasation is global, the only work around is to hide some field for specific type of operations (READ/WRITE). Perhaps it will change in future and creators will add such functionality, or some side library will be writen.